# Antlr4 order of token in lexer

Tags: .net-core, antlr4

lexer grammar

```
DESC: D | D E S C;
.
.
.
INCREMENTOPTION: S | H | M | D;
```

parser grammar:

```
sortExpression: integer? sortFieldList Desc = DESC?;
.
.
.
incrementOption: integer INCREMENTOPTION;
```

in the case of input 'd' i have a problem.

each of DESC or INCREMENTOPTION token be the upper token in lexer that is matched and the other one not matched
what can i do?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
sortExpression. : integer? sortFieldList desc?;
incrementOption : integer incrementoption;
desc            : DESC | SINGLE_D;
incrementoption : SINGLE_D | SINGLE_S_H_M;

DESC            : D E S C;
SINGLE_D        : D;
SINGLE_S_H_M    : S | H | M;
```

Comment: its actually works but is there any way to do not face with this problem?! i have same problem in many situations and fixed them with something like this

Comment: No, this is the way.